# How go give data from another activity to a custom ListView adapter?

Tags: java, android

I am using a custom `ListView` adapter, and I want the symbols to change accordingly to what is pressed in the "Settings" activity (`ListView` with the custom adapter is in "Home" activity). I send data to the "Home" activity using `SharedPreferences`, yet it seems I can't do that in the adapter. How to do that?

```html
public class ShowcaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Coin>{
        private static final String TAG = "PersonalListAdapter";

        private Context mContext;
        int mResource;

        private boolean EUROIsChecked;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

    private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String sharedPrefs, int modePrivate) {
    }

    EUROIsChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECKBOXEURO, false);

    public ShowcaseAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Coin> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        String name = getItem(position).getName();
        String price = getItem(position).getPrice();
        String change = getItem(position).getChange();
        String number = getItem(position).getNumber();

        Coin coin = new Coin(name, price, change, number);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_box);
        TextView tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price_box);
        TextView tvChange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.change_box);
        TextView tvNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number_box);

        double pricedouble = Double.parseDouble(price);

        pricedouble = Math.round(pricedouble * 10000.0) / 10000.0;

        tvName.setText(name);
        tvPrice.setText(String.valueOf(pricedouble) + "$");
        tvNumber.setText(number);

        Log.d("DEBUG", change);

        double changenum;
        changenum = Double.parseDouble(change);

        if(changenum >= 0){
            tvChange.setTextColor(Color.rgb(52,124,60));
            tvName.setTextColor(Color.rgb(52,124,60));
        }
        else{
            tvChange.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            tvName.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        tvChange.setText(change + "%");

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar added the code. The bonus function appears and `getBoolean` becomes unknown

Comment: If you want to get a `SharedPreferences` inside your `Adapter`, you can call `getSharedPreferences()` on the `Context` passed into the constructor.